# Parsing Html using Mojo::Dom in perl

Tags: html, perl, dom

i am trying to parse a html content using Mojo::Dom in perl

The html content is

```
<div id="description" class="markdown description col7" style="display: block;">
Hello everyone !        #<---- data which i want      
 <div id="shop-about">
  <div class="shop-about-message">
   <h2>      
   Text
    </h2>
  </div>
<div class="avatars">
            <div class="avatar">
                <a href="link">

                </a>
                <div class="avatar-name">
                    Jacqueline
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>            </div>
                    </div>
```

The code i have used is.,

`my $desc=$dom->find('#description');
        print $desc;`

this print all the data inside the div. but i only want the content from parent div. please give some suggestion .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`say $dom->at("#description")->text;`

Answer (score 2):

From the [perldoc](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM)

```
#Find
say '$dom->at(\'#description\')->text';
say $dom->at('#description')->text;

say '$dom->find(\'h2\')->text';
say $dom->find('h2')->text;

say '$dom->find(\'[id]\')->attr(\'id\')';
say $dom->find('[id]')->attr('id');
```

Outputs:

```
$dom->at('#description')->text
Hello everyone ! #<---- data which i want

$dom->find('h2')->text
Text

$dom->find('[id]')->attr('id')
description
shop-about
```

As you can see, `$dom->at('#description')->text` looks to do what you're looking for.